「編集の承認待ち」を表すパーツ内で、Markdownが適切に反映されていない
前提
信用度が一定段階に到達していない場合、質問の編集を行った際に直ちに反映されるのではなく、承認待ち状態になります。
事象
その際、質問本文の上部に「承認待ち」であることを伝えるパーツが表示されるのですが、中でMarkdownを用いているものの、適切にHTMLに変換されていないようです。
（直近の2質問に対する編集で確認を行い、どちらも同様の事象であったことは確認）

該当箇所のHTMLをブラウザでのソース閲覧で確認すると、下記のようになっていました。
    <div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
                    <div>
            <aside class="s-notice s-notice__warning post-notice js-post-notice mb16" role="status">
        <div class="d-flex fd-column fw-nowrap">
            <div class="d-flex fw-nowrap">
                <div class="flex--item wmn0 fl1 lh-lg">
                    <div class="flex--item fl1 lh-lg">
                            <div>
                                **編集を提案いただきありがとうございます**！
                                信頼できるコミュニティメンバーによって <a href="/suggested-edits/4856">承認</a> されるまで、あなたにのみ表示されます。
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</aside>

    </div>

見解
ソース内の「承認」に付与されたリンクもシステム内でMarkdownを用いている場合、例えば閉じる側の**の直後にスペースがないことが挙動の原因として考えられます。
（リンクの側はHTML変換後のソースを見る限り、リンクの文法の前後に半角スペースが挿入されているようです）

「承認されるまで～」の部分 (リンク) は純粋な Markdown ではなく、システム側で変数を展開する形になりますが、原文/翻訳ともに前後に空白文字を入れています。 https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15767

問題箇所の翻訳は こちら で、一見問題無さそうに見えるんですよね。スタッフによる手助け (調査) が必要となるかもしれません。

Traducir で、試しに ございます**！ から ございます** ！ に変えてみました（** の後に半角スペースを入れました）。少し待つと反映されます。これで様子を見てみます。

ページフッタのリビジョンを見ると更新がかかっているようです。"rev 2024.9.9.14969"

タイミングがあったので、質問の編集を実施してみました。現行の翻訳設定で ** が <b> と適切に判定されているのを確認できています。「半角スペースの有無による翻訳元との挙動差異」についての調査+確認までこの質問内で扱わなくても良いのであれば、想定している動作になっているスクリーンショットと合わせて解決の回答をしようと考えています。

Traducir で翻訳を ございます**！ から ございます** ！ に変えてみたところ、直ったようです。
